# Wheather google return GCM registration ID on the basis of Udid of device and sender id?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How google generate `GCM` id on basis of **senderID**.
we only send **senderID** to `GCM` is google return `GCM` registration ID on the basis of Udid of device and sender id ?
in case of android phones the udids are not unique some times

**I want to know Google stores what information along with senderID to send message back to Device.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Google knows what information is sent to the GCM server, when registering with a SenderID. But it's not hard to guess these information will be sent:

1. Your google/gmail email address used to activate the phone.
2. A unique ID of the phone, it could be based on SIM, IMEI or ESN, or even the ANDROID_ID string.
3. Package name of your app.

Answer (score 0):

By using this code you can generete an unique device ID in android It will never change its a combination of number generated using the Ids of hardware...

```
public String getDeviceID() {

/*String Return_DeviceID = USERNAME_and_PASSWORD.getString(DeviceID_key,"Guest");
return Return_DeviceID;*/

TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String m_szImei = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires
// READ_PHONE_STATE

// 2 compute DEVICE ID
String m_szDevIDShort = "35"
+ // we make this look like a valid IMEI
Build.BOARD.length() % 10 + Build.BRAND.length() % 10
+ Build.CPU_ABI.length() % 10 + Build.DEVICE.length() % 10
+ Build.DISPLAY.length() % 10 + Build.HOST.length() % 10
+ Build.ID.length() % 10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length() % 10
+ Build.MODEL.length() % 10 + Build.PRODUCT.length() % 10
+ Build.TAGS.length() % 10 + Build.TYPE.length() % 10
+ Build.USER.length() % 10; // 13 digits
// 3 android ID - unreliable
String m_szAndroidID = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
// 4 wifi manager, read MAC address - requires
// android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE or comes as null
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String m_szWLANMAC = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
// 5 Bluetooth MAC address android.permission.BLUETOOTH required
BluetoothAdapter m_BluetoothAdapter = null; // Local Bluetooth adapter
m_BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String m_szBTMAC = m_BluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
System.out.println("m_szBTMAC "+m_szBTMAC);

// 6 SUM THE IDs
String m_szLongID = m_szImei + m_szDevIDShort + m_szAndroidID+ m_szWLANMAC + m_szBTMAC;
System.out.println("m_szLongID "+m_szLongID);
MessageDigest m = null;
try {
m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
                }
m.update(m_szLongID.getBytes(), 0, m_szLongID.length());
byte p_md5Data[] = m.digest();

String m_szUniqueID = new String();
for (int i = 0; i < p_md5Data.length; i++) {
int b = (0xFF & p_md5Data[i]);
// if it is a single digit, make sure it have 0 in front (proper
// padding)
if (b <= 0xF)
m_szUniqueID += "0";
// add number to string
m_szUniqueID += Integer.toHexString(b);
}
m_szUniqueID = m_szUniqueID.toUpperCase();

Log.i("-------------DeviceID------------", m_szUniqueID);
Log.d("DeviceIdCheck", "DeviceId that generated MPreferenceActivity:"+m_szUniqueID);

return m_szUniqueID;

}
```

Comment: when i hit GCM Google server with senderID of app will it store senderID along with this generated device UDID ?

Comment: Actually I dint worked in GCM so am not aware about that...Sorry

Comment: Why not just use IMEI for this?  Isn't IMEI guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: IMEI is unique but for some set of device some faults are there since lakhs of devices are in circulation we cant figure where the that set devices are...